# Laravel 5 + Postgresql Connection

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, pgadmin

I have some problem in Postgre SQL, i can't connect my project Laravel 5 into Postgre SQL(i'm using PG Admin III), of course i remember the password in the first time i installed the Postgresql. but i think the problem is default username for database PostgreSQL, i try use "root",and "postgres" but both is failed. maybe someone know a default username for postgresql

PS: i've already configuring default into pgsql in database.php file and .env file

note: the error is (i tried in tinker laravel) "***PDO exception with message could not find any driver***"

Comment: postgres is the default owner for a postgresql instance and thus will always be an "option" to connect. However you need to ensure that 1) you know the postgres password :) try testing it on the command line via psql -U postgres -W. If that works ensure you have allowed remote connections via $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf